# replacing a single word in a string

Tags: c, string

i have a null terminated and dynamically allocated string called 'text_buff' , which contain's the word "bar". i want to replace this word with another word of my choice, that can be longer or shorter than the original one.

here's my code up until now, i can't seem to figure out what am i doing wrong.

```
        char * toswap = "newword";
        int diff = strlen(toswap)-strlen("bar");
        int wlocation = strstr(text_buff,"bar")-text_buff;
        if (diff > 0) {
            text_buff = realloc(text_buff,strlen(text_buff)+diff);
            for (i=strlen(text_buff) ; i > wlocation+strlen("bar") -1; --i ){
                text_buff[i+diff] = text_buff[i];
            }
            for (i = 0 ; i < strlen("bar")+1; ++i){
                text_buff[wlocation+i] = toswap[i];

            }
        } else if (diff < 0){
                for (i=wlocation+diff ; i <strlen(text_buff);++i ){
                    text_buff[i]=text_buff[i-diff];
                }
                for (i = 0 ; i < strlen("bar")+1; ++i){
                    text_buff[wlocation+i] = toswap[i];
                }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck it is just pure wrong. this code is only the direction i was thinking of when trying to solve the problem. it work's only on 5 char string but beyond that it starts overriding other words in the text_buff.

Comment: I'm looking for a proper solution to replace words within a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong loop condition when inserting the new word:

```
        for (i = 0 ; i < strlen("bar")+1; ++i){
            text_buff[wlocation+i] = toswap[i];
        }
```

It should be:

```
        for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(toswap); ++i){
            text_buff[wlocation+i] = toswap[i];
        }
```

Other than that you are missing error handling. If this is a school assignment you can probably manage without error handling, though.

Comment: but can anyone come up with a better idea? i think my code is too messy for such an oparation.

Comment: I would use `memcpy` and `memmove` instead of `for` loops. Doing so will make the code half as long and easier to read. Your basic idea is correct - this is the work you need to do to change a string in C.

Comment: what kind of error handling are you talking about ? realloc returning NULL ? because i do have that one in mind of course, just i usually put the NULL checks after I get my function functional. other than that, any other error's i need to check for ?

Comment: `strstr` returns `NULL` if the string doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You forget 1 character for the final '\0';

```
text_buff = realloc(text_buff,strlen(text_buff)+diff);
```

It should be

```
text_buff = realloc(text_buff,strlen(text_buff)+diff + 1);
```